# cant run sh script in mac terminal because cant find path for associated files in unzipped directory

Tags: macos, path

I have downloaded a .sh script to root my phone.  I have useda mac for years,but never needed to use terminal.  The result is a string of unfindable commands from the unzipped directory.  Here is a copy of the batchfile process:

Johns-Mac-mini:~ jm$ /Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot\ (1)/runmemac.sh ---------------------------------------------------------------
                  Easy rooting toolkit (v2.0)
                   created by DooMLoRD
   Modified for Kindle Fire for  Linux/Mac by Max Lee at RootGalaxyNote.com
        using exploit zergRush (Revolutionary Team)

### Credits go to all those involved in making this possible!

[*] This script will:

     (1) root ur device using latest zergRush exploit (10 Nov) 
     (2) install Busybox (1.18.4)

     (3) install SU files (binary: 3.0.3 and apk: 3.0.6)

 [*] Before u begin:
     (1) enable USB DEBUGGING
           from (Menu\Settings\Applications\Development)
     (2) enable UNKNOWN SOURCES
           from (Menu\Settings\Applications)
     (3) [OPTIONAL] increase screen timeout to 10 minutes

### (4) connect USB cable to PHONE and then connect 2 computer

--- STARTING ----
--- WAITING FOR DEVICE
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 24: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- cleaning
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 26: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- pushing zergRush
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 28: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- correcting permissions
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 30: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- executing zergRush
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 32: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- WAITING FOR DEVICE TO RECONNECT
if it gets stuck over here for a long time then try:
   disconnect usb cable and reconnect it
   toggle USB DEBUGGING (first disable it then enable it)
--- DEVICE FOUND
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 38: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- pushing busybox
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 40: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- correcting permissions
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 42: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- remounting /system
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 44: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- copying busybox to /system/xbin/
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 46: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- correcting ownership
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 48: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- correcting permissions
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 50: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- installing busybox
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 52: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 53: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- pushing SU binary
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 55: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- correcting ownership
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 57: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- correcting permissions
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 59: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- correcting symlinks
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 61: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 62: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- pushing Superuser app
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 64: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- cleaning
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 66: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- rebooting
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 68: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
--- WAITING FOR DEVICE
/Users/jm/Downloads/GalaxyNoteRoot (1)/runmemac.sh: line 70: ./adb-mac: No such file or directory
All Done, Galaxy Note ROOTED!!!
Check out RootGalaxyNote.com for more cool hacks!
Johns-Mac-mini:~ jm$

How do I gain access to the other files in the directory?

John

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but for people who have only just now encountered the problem. I just had the exact same problem as you did.

What I did was in the terminal I changed directory to the directory of the image files. 
Then open the .sh file with any text editor, and copy the instructions in one by one into the terminal.

Hope it helped!